# Adding column description of one spreadsheet sheet in another spreadsheet of same excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, spreadsheet

I have an excel sheet having 4 different spreadsheets. I need description of column header of three spreadsheets in 4th spread sheet.
Example:
Suppose I have  sheet 1 with 6 headers for 6 columns, Sheet 2 with 14 headers for 14 columns and sheet 3 with 8 headers for 8 columns. Now when I click on one of the header in sheet 1 then system should be able to open sheet 4 that contains the header name and description of the header.

Please let me know weather this is applicable. If yes please provide solution for this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: And we generally provide suggestions to help you along your way to you coming up with your own solution.

Comment: What @gns100 is saying is: please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Automatically open the new Worksheet with the header and header columns data?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use the `HYPERLINK` function to create the "jump" ability as well as the column header for the users to see on each sheet.

Use this:

```
=HYPERLINK("#" & ADDRESS(XMATCH("The column header for this column",Sheet4!$A$1:$A$28,0),2,1,1,"Sheet4"),"The column header for this column")
```

This assumes a vertical list of headers down column A on Sheet4 with their descriptions in column B next to them.

Of course, where it shows `The column header for this column` you'd edit that to have the column header you desire for that particular column. And the sheet name might need editing as well.

You CANNOT then do the same thing in the cell with the header entry on Sheet 4. Believe it or not, that creates an infinite loop between the two... instead of simply taking you to the cell, it does that and then fires the hyperlink there, bringing you back... apparently. In any case, if you want a return click to be possible, you can set the hyperlink for it on the description cell instead of the Sheet 4 cell that has the header matches. However, that will not return the user to the precise same view of the sheet the user had before clicking to the description. The formula would be slightly different in that the `XMATCH` will look across the header row for a match, not down a column, and the result is now the column in the `ADDRESS` function, not the row:

```
=HYPERLINK("#" & ADDRESS(2, XMATCH("The column header for this description", Sheet1!$A$1:$F$1, 0), 1, 1, "Sheet1"), "The description for the header on this row")
```